# Where should I place electrical outlets in waterfall island?

Tags: receptacle, kitchens, code-compliance, kitchen-island

I'm remodeling my kitchen.
The existing island have a raised bar and two electrical outlets (on its the backsplash).

We are cutting down the raised wall and moving to a waterfall countertop but then, I don't know what to do with the outlets.

1. Do we still need the two outlets or can it be reduced to one?
2. Where should they go while still being in compliance with electrical building code?

The finished island will look exactly like this one. I added the actual dimensions to make it easier.
Based on it's size and the 6" max overhand rule (which I don't know if still exists), it looks I have a problem.

[image]

Comment: Apart from regs, ask the one who does the cooking!!!

Answer (score 2):

According to [NEC 2020](https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=822.0), you need 1 for the first 9 square feet and another for each 18 square feet.

92" x 39" = ~ 25 square feet. So you need at least 2.

I would put one duplex receptacle on each end. That would be better than flush mounted receptacles (big concern about spills). But you can certainly have *more* receptacles, and that may be a good idea. For example, 4 - one near each corner - would allow for blender or other appliances on the "work" side while leaving the "stool side" receptacles available for phone chargers.

Comment: As a mention, I believe there has to be 2 because the sink creates 2 work surfaces??

Comment: That may be, but have to be 2 anyway due to size.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Based on the sample drawings in the article, once you have the minimum required outlets per sq ft, they can be all put together on a single side, they don't have to be distributed through the space, is that right? If yes I could have the required two on the less visible side of the island (cutting through the granite), and then two more about 12 inches (or less) from the counter, in the "stoll side"? To your point I would get the required and then some and would leave the visible side of the stone pristine, no distracting outlets. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes it would still require 2 anyways, but the sink determines placement. One on each end?

Comment: My reading of the quoted section of NEC 2020 is that there are no specific placements required, except possibly (as with peninsula) 1 within 2 feet of the end. But it is possible that there are other requirements that I am not aware of, and also that an inspector *might* say "1 every 4 feet just like a regular counter" even if that is not the official rule. Not sure why you would need *any* cutting through granite if you mount on end caps, underneath overhangs, etc.

Comment: @Jack That's exactly what I wrote: *I would put one duplex receptacle on each end.*

Comment: It was written for the sake of the OP who eludes to placing them both on the blind end...

Comment: I apologize if I'm being redundant or just stupid  :-) but I'm still a little confused regarding placement. The island has 4 sides, in layman terms: front is where the front of the cabinets are so it is a "no". Left and right is where the "side panels" are. Because of the waterfall thingie these panels are granite, reason I said whatever goes on the side has to go through the granite. Then we have the back which is a wall (drywall) with a granite overhand of 9". So if not in the back, under the 9" overhang and not through the side granite...where would that be?

Comment: So the *side panels, floor to countertop* are granite? That is a bit unusual. Back really wouldn't work - practical or likely code - because the overhang would make those mostly inaccessible.

Comment: Yep. This is the waterfall concept. Stone top and sides. One side of it is really visible when you enter the kitchen so it would be nice to have it clean. The other side is towards a wall so if I had two outlets in there (on the granite panel) it would be fine. Assuming the code is not clear regarding placement I might do it. I will try to contact a city inspector next week and see if they have any input as well.